# Why is this set not a group?

Tags: group-theory

So the group $Z_8 - \{0\}$ does not form a group under multiplication modulo $8$.  The reason being is because its not closed as $2 \cdot 4 = 0$.

I understand what closure is.  If $a$ and $b$ are in the group then $a \cdot b$ must be in the group, but $2$ and $4$ aren't in this group so why does that mean its not a group?

Comment: Why do you say $2$ and $4$ aren't in the group?

Comment: might want to check the definition of $\mathbb{Z}_8$

Comment: The equivalence classes [2] and [4] are in the set you've defined. Don't call the elements of $\mathbb{Z}_n$ by their $\mathbb{Z}$ names.

Comment: Yeah I was wondering because Z is the integers, but what does it mean then by the ${0}$?  I thought that just meant the the group just had $0$.

Comment: The set is {1,2,3,4,5,6,7} and 2 and 4 are, of course in the set.  Why on earth do you think they are not?  0 is not in the set.  So with mult over 0 you have 2x4=0 so the operator isn't closed.  Also not every element has an inverse (2 x b $\ne$ 1 for any b).  So it's not a group.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The set you're talking about - $\mathbb{Z}/8\mathbb{Z}-\{0\}$ - consists of everything in $\mathbb{Z}/8\mathbb{Z}$ **except for** $0$ (or rather, $[0]$ - it's a bit sloppy notation). That's what the "$-$" means. So $2$ and $4$ (or rather, $[2]$ and $[4]$) are in the set, but their product is not.

Answer (score 0):

Every group must have an inverse for each of its element in itself, which is not the case here. This is because $8 $ not being a prime, there exists many elements, like $ 2,4,6 $ which do not have a multiplicative inverse

Answer (score 0):

The set (which is not a group) is {1,2,3,4,5,6,7}

with an operation with values given in the following table:

1x1 = 1; 1x2 = 2; 1x3=3; 1x4=4; 1x5=5; 1x6=6; 1x7=7

2x1 = 2; 2x2 = 4; 2x3=3; **2x4=0**;2x5=2; 2x6=4;2x7=6

3x1 = 3; 3x2=6; 3x3=1; 3x4=4; 3x5=7; 3x6=2; 3x7 = 5

4x1 = 4; **4x2 = 0**; 4x3=4; **4x4=0**; 4x5=4; **4x6=0**; 4x7=4

.... etc....

As you can see the bold entries have $a x b \not \in $ Set.  So the set can not be a group.

So... I don't really understand where you are having issues.